# Unable to open file in C++ even after specifying full path

Tags: c++

My next step is to try getcwd(), but I'm wondering if there is an error in my code that I'm not seeing. student_status.txt is in the right folder, and I have tried the full file path.

Also, the code does compile and notify me that the file didn't open.

Any ideas?

```
 using namespace tenPoint;
 int main()
 {
    string name;
    char grade;
    double average;

    cout << "test";

    ifstream fileRead;
    fileRead.open("student_status.txt");
    if (fileRead.is_open())
    {
        while (!fileRead.eof())
        {
            getline(fileRead, name);
            fileRead >> average;
            fileRead.ignore();

            switch (finalGrade)
            {
            case F:
                grade = 'F';
            case D:
                grade = 'D';
            case C:
                grade = 'C';
            case B:
                grade = 'B';
            case A:
                grade = 'A';
            }

            cout << name << " " << average << " " << finalGrade << endl;
        }
        fileRead.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "file wasn't open";
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's in the right place? and you need full path with DOUBLE back slashes

Comment: make sure you have read privileges on the file as well...

Comment: quick question : tell me how you are specifying the full path.

Comment: What IDE are you using? If you're using something like Visual Studio, the compiled executable ends up in a different directory than your solution/source.

Comment: Thank you all so much! I'll look at these things. One of them has to be it.

Answer (score 1):

I had to comment out everything inside your `while` loop (`finalGrade` not defined), change the namespace to `std` and add `#include` lines for `iostream` and `fstream`to get the program to compile. Placed the source file on my desktop, outputted g++ executable to my desktop, placed a file named 'student_status.txt' on the desktop. The program worked fine, it opened the file for reading. No need for any absolute paths for me. I'm on OS X.

First ensure your filename is correct, symbols, capitalization and all, and that its in the same directory as the */executable/* output file. Perhaps try replacing

```
 fileRead.open("student_status.txt");
```

with

```
 fileRead.open("./student_status.txt");
```

Note the `./` which tells the program to look in the current directory.

Comment: Um...yeah because I left out all but the relevant code. But way to go buddy!